# how to grow the disk size parted?

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, parted

I have a big doubt regarding how works parted, let me explain

I have two machines

1. machine with hard drive 60GB
2. machine with hard drive 120GB

In the machine 1 I set up an Ubuntu image with the following :

- `/dev/sda1` `EFI` = 500MB as logical partition
- `/dev/sda2` `Swap` = 3GB as primary partition
- `/dev/sda3` `/` ext4 = 8GB as primary partition

How can you see I don't use all disk space which is 60GB, and then I do a backup for this image with clonezilla, once the backup is ready I downloaded this Ubuntu image in the machine 2 (which has 120GB of hard drive)

At this point all is ok, but when I try to grow the disk to 120GB with the following command

```
parted -s /dev/sda resizepart 3 120GB
```

Note :  with values greater than 60GB parted fail

I had always the following message :

```
Error : can't have the end before the start! (start sector=7172092 length=7062916)
```

attached fdisk -l output

```
Device    Start     End       Sectors     Size    Type
/dev/sda1 2048      1171455   1169408     571M    EFI System
/dev/sda2 1171456   7172095   6000640     2.9G    Linux Swap
/dev/sda3 7172096   23173119  16001024    7.6G    Linux Filesystem
```

so i supposed that when i cloned the image of 60GB on the machine which has the hard drive of 120GB the image has an id in somewhere that parted check and thus fail because this id tell to parted that the current disk size is no greater than 60GB, but this is only a assumption, please correct me if i'm wrong

besides that i have to comment that if i tell to parted the following command

```
parted -s /dev/sda resizepart 3 60GB
```

it does not fail, and grow the partition /dev/sda3 to 60GB successfully

as additional info, with gparted does the job, i mean it increase the partition /dev/sda3 without any issue, but the think is that i need to do this in a command line